# Right Keytab for Nifi Processor

Tags: apache-nifi, hortonworks-dataflow

I have Nifi 3 node cluster (Installed Via Hortonworks Data Flow - HDF ) in Kerborized environment. As part of installation Ambari has created nifi service keytab .
Hi

Can I use this nifi.service.keytab for configuring processors like PutHDFS who talks to Hadoop services ?

The nifi.service.keytab is machine specific and always expect principal names with machine information. ex nifi/HOSTNAME@REALM

If I configure my Processor with nfii/NODE1_Hostname@REALM information then I see kerberos authentication exception in other two nodes.

How do I dynamically resolve hostname to use nifi service  keytab  ?

Comment: The NiFi services use a "service principal name" in the form `service/host.fqdn@REALM`. The clients use a base "principal name" in the form `someone@REALM`; the authentication process is done in 2 steps, first the client gets a TGT *(ticket-granting ticket)* as a proof of identity, then it uses the TGT to get a service ticket for accessing the service on a **specific** host. I.e. in case of failover to another host, it has to get another service ticket; the resolution is done automatically by the NiFi client lib.

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter Problem is if I configure service keytab in Nifi processor , it doe not dynamically resolves hostname. Because of which processor starts failing where principal does not match machine name.

Comment: Yes, that's why you need **three** different entries in Kerberos directories, and 3 different keytabs, one per node... Unless you use Microsoft AD as Kerberos KDC -- it works a bit differently (for AD, SPN are not IDs but attributes of standard accounts)

Comment: Remember, Kerberos was defined *decades* before distributed processing (or even load balancers) became popular. And it is very cautious about host authentication (incl. reverse DNS scans) among other thibgs.

Answer (score 1):

The keytab principal name field supports [Apache NiFi Expression Language](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/expression-language-guide.html), so you can use an expression like the following: `nifi/${hostname()}@REALM`, and each node will resolve that expression (independently) to something like `nifi/host1.nifi.com@REALM` or `nifi/host2.nifi.com@REALM`, etc.

If you do not want it to be the explicit hostname, you can also set an environment variable on each node (`export NIFI_KEYTAB_HOSTNAME="modified_host_format_1"`, etc.) and reference the environment variable in the EL expression the same way: `nifi/${NIFI_KEYTAB_HOSTNAME}@REALM`.